# How to include fields in api server and remove it before returning to results to client in Graphql

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, graphql-tools

I have a Node.js GraphQL server. From the client, I am trying get all the user entries using a query like this:

```
{
    user {
        name
        entries {
            title
            body
        }
    }
}
```

In the Node.js GraphQL server, however I want to return user entries that are currently valid based on `publishDate` and `expiryDate` in the entries object.

For example:

```
{
    "user": "john",
    "entries": [
        { 
          "title": "entry1",
          "body": "body1",
          "publishDate": "2019-02-12",
          "expiryDate": "2019-02-13"
        },
        { 
          "title": "entry2",
          "body": "body2",
          "publishDate": "2019-02-13",
          "expiryDate": "2019-03-01"
        },
        { 
          "title": "entry3",
          "body": "body3",
          "publishDate": "2020-01-01",
          "expiryDate": "2020-01-31"
        }
    ]
}
```

should return this

```
{
    "user": "john",
    "entries": [
        { 
          "title": "entry2",
          "body": "body2",
          "publishDate": "2019-02-13",
          "expiryDate": "2019-03-01"
        }
    ]
}
```

The `entries` is fetched via a `delegateToSchema` call (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-delegation.html#delegateToSchema) and I don't have an option to pass publishDate and expiryDate as query parameters. Essentially, I need to get the results and then filter them in memory.

The issue I face is that the original query doesn't have `publishDate` and `expiryDate` in it to support this. Is there a way to add these fields to delegateToSchema call and then remove them while sending them back to the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`transformResult`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-transforms.html#Transform)

Implementation details are:

1. At [delegateToSchema](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-delegation.html#delegateToSchema) you need to define `transforms` array.
2. At [Transform](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-transforms.html#Transform) you need to define `transformResult` function for filtering results.
3. If you have ability to send arguments to remote GraphQL server, then you should use 
   [`transformRequest`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-transforms.html#Transform)

Comment: Hi galkin. Thanks for your comments. `transformRequest` was exactly what I was looking for!!! :)